# How to add a number to string\d

Tags: vim, find-and-replace

I want to replace a file's all `string\d\+`
For example string10 to string 20.I tried using `s/\(string\)\d\+/\1\=submatch(0)+10`
I know `\=` is judge `\1` is exist or not .But `help: submatch` use like  this.how can  I correct this  command Or there  is another  method to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> :s/\(string\)\d\+/\1\=submatch(0)+10
> ```

You're close:

- You cannot mix normal replacement (`\1`) and [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression). Once you use the latter, the *entire* replacement has to be an expression.
- In order to increment the number, it needs to be captured separately. `submatch(0)` is the entire match; you cannot simply add `10` to it.
- If you want to replace *all* occurrences, you still need to add the `/g` flag and a `:[range]`; else, only the first match of the current line will be incremented.

Here's one variant with full capture:

```
:%substitute/\(string\)\(\d\+\)/\=submatch(1) . (submatch(2) + 10)/g
```

As you do nothing with the `string` prefix, we can alternatively assert on it (but not include it) via [`:help /\zs`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs); we don't need any capture then:

```
:%substitute/string\zs\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 10/g
```